# Twitter SSO always granted

Tags: ios, twitter, account

```
- (void)authTwitter {

    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
        ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

        [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType
                                                           options:nil
                                                        completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error){
            if (granted) {
                 NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
    //           always there, but accounts array is empty
            } else {

            }
        }];
```

I was expecting to see some prompt from iOS, but granted always YES. 
I DO NOT have account set-up on my iPhone.

Does it mean that it's too much time I've been programming and should go outside? Or I simply missed something?

iOS 7, both device and simulator have same behaviour.

Comment: If you delete the app and reinstall it, does it still not prompt?

Comment: yes, it still doesn't prompt

Comment: Apparently you can enable access to twitter accounts without having any. The prompt seem to appear only once, later the user is able to change decision at Settings > Privacy.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that after removing app and installing again -> it appears on twitter settings with value which I set before...

Comment: Strange thing that I've never allowed that application to use twitter account, so I've never seen prompt exactly for that app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already there.  Completion block should be:

```
   {
   bool actuallyGranted = granted;

   NSArray *accounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
   if (!accounts || ([accounts count] == 0))
      actuallyGranted = false;

   if (actuallyGranted) 
      {

      }

   else
      {

      }
   }
```

A similar call for FB does not need this - value for "granted" will be correct.  I'm assuming the special case needed for twitter is an iOS bug.

Comment: yes, I've already done like that, so you confirm that bug? Btw on simulator 64bit I've got that prompt...

Comment: filed with Apple. I don't have a way to handle errors in this case ...the above at least allows me to bail and post an "add twitter account to your device" dialog.  This may be avoidable by using the twitter sdk in place of the above but I haven't tried that.  Also, I've seen some rare, non-reproducible exceptions thrown from requestAccessToAccountsWithType so wrap that in a try/catch.